# MySQL Query result based on another table result

Tags: mysql

I need to query a datas from a table which should be present in another table.

for example,
I have 2 tables

```
Table 1
comp    col1   col2    col3
a         0      v       v
b         0      v       v
c         0      v       v
d         0      v       v

Table 2
name    col4
a         0
b         1
c         0
d         1
```

my result should be from table 1 as

```
comp    col1   col2    col3
a         0      v       v
c         0      v       v
```

the record for b and d value is 1, so it should be retrieved from table 1.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Thanks.

Comment: No doubts on my side. If you need to query that, then have a go! Or did you have any question here?

Comment: I think the question is asking how to pass a query result as a variable in a sql query...ie Can I query table 2 to select which table to return the results from ....ie a  should not return at all... and c should not return a result either ....otherwise I have no clue what he is asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be done with `inner join`

```
select
t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.comp = t2.comp
where t2.col4 = 0
```

Comment: Hi abhik, thanks..but it results the records from table

Comment: Did not understand what you mean, as per the expected output in your question the above query should do the job.